# 2D Arrays with 'Creature' Movement Error (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

For this assignment, I have to make a creature 'C' be on a environment (20x20 array) and have it move.

The first time, it works and moves the creature, but the second time+, it doesn't.
[image]

So here's the code. Yes, I'm aware it's pretty messy, but I'm still kinda new to c++ (I wouldn't mind corrections :D). Also, as part of the assignment, the creature has to be in a LifeForm class.

Click [here](http://cpp.sh/6baz) for a cpp.sh link to run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class LifeForm{
    public:
    int x, y;
    char array[20][20];

    string name(){
        return "Control";
    }

    char symbol(){
        return 'C';
    }

    void xy(){
        x = (rand() % 18) + 1; //random position in x
        y = (rand() % 18) + 1; //random position in y
        array[x][y] = symbol();
    }

    void step(){
        for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
                array[a][b] = '0';
            }
        }
        array[x + 1][y + 1] = symbol();
        if (x > 19 || x < 2 || y > 19 || y < 2){
            cout << "The creature cannot move any further without leaving the environment!" << endl;
            array[x][y] = '0';
            array[x - 1][y - 1] = symbol();
        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        find(array);
        for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
            for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
                cout << array[a][b] << " ";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void step10(){
        //todo

    }

    void find(char array[][20]){
        for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
            for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
                if (array[a][b] != '0'){
                    cout << "Found Creature '" << name() << "' in row " << a + 1 << ", column " << b + 1 << "." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    LifeForm creature;
    srand((unsigned) time(0)); //randomize
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++){ //initilize array to all 0's
        for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
            creature.array[a][b] = '0';
        }
    }
    creature.xy();
    creature.find(creature.array);
    for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++){ //display the array
        for (int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
            cout << creature.array[a][b] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    creature.step();

    string a;
    bool abc;
    do{
    cout << "\n--- What would you like to do? --------------" << endl;
    cout << "S for Step | S10 for Step 10 | E for Exit" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    if (a == "S" || a == "s") {
        creature.step();
        abc = true;
    }else if (a == "S10" || a == "s10") {
        creature.step10();
        abc = true;
    }else{
        abc = false;
        system("pause");
    }
    }while(abc == true);
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm trying to get the creature to move more then once when the user chooses to, but it stays at the same position.

Comment: Only call `srand` once in your program.

Comment: Hmm, didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `step` you never update the current position of the Creature. In this line `array[x + 1][y + 1] = symbol();` you update the array. But you should rewrite it to this:

```
x++;
y++;
array[x][y] = symbol();
```

By doing this, you ensure that the current position of the creature is updated correctly when you change the representation of the position (The array you draw on the screen).